# Telnet to remote server VM in python

Tags: python, ssh, telnet

I had some success using telnetlib to connect to a locally running VM and access its console but I am testing out replicating this with a remote server running the VM instead. Typically, I would SSH into this remote server and then invoke telnet to access the VMs console so I tried turning it into a simple python script like below

```py
import paramiko

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect("IP", username="USER", password="PSWD")

tn = ssh_client.invoke_shell()

tn.send(f"telnet {IP} {PORT}\r")
tn.recv(4096)
tn.send("foo\r")
```

Is there a better way to go about this, this method doesn't seem to be consistent and will often return the output of the servers prompts when logging in. Perhaps a way to forward the port of the remotely hosted VM to access with telnetlib locally?

Comment: If you are getting inconsistent results, copy-paste all of them to the question. Without details, we can only guess, we can't directly help you.

Comment: Put `tn.recv(4096)` to a loop, wait for all lines you are expecting, and only then send `tn.send("foo\r")`.

Comment: Don't send `\r`, most command don't understand it. Send `\n`, and if it doesn't work, send `\r\n`.

Comment: `f"telnet {IP} {PORT}"` contains an injection vulnerability, e.g. if `IP == '0 0; rm -rf ~ #'`, it will remove the contents of the user's home directory.  To fix it, do `import pipes`, and use `pipes.quote(IP)` instead of `IP`. Similarly for `PORT`. (This fix assumes that both the client and the server run a form of Unix, i.e. not Windows.)

Comment: The SSH protocol supports proper tunneling -- no `telnet` or telnetlib or anything else like it needed. Use it the way it's designed, don't try to hack up some backdoor-ish "tunnel" going over a command execution.

Comment: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/main/demos/rforward.py is a place to start.